# Xcode Debugger Doesn't Begin Session When App Runs

Tags: xcode

I'm using version 12.4 of Xcode, and when I run my app to test it, the debugger never starts a session. When I open the Debug Navigator, the message "No Debug Session" stays, and none of the normal analytics data appears.

I am running my app through Xcode onto my iPhone 12 Pro. It requires the use of the camera, and in fact the part I need the debugger for also requires the camera, so I can't use a simulator to see if that magically fixes it.
I also looked through every setting I could find that mentioned "Debug" or "Debugger", but nothing I could find changed anything.

Also, I downloaded a random tutorial app and ran that through Xcode on my iPhone, and the debugger boots up as expected.

I am completely lost and really need a GDB/LLDB tool to debug my code, so any help is greatly appreciated, as I could not find a single person or post with a similar problem to mine, and all of the Debugger tutorials and Apple Documentation are outdated and useless.

**EDIT:** Here is the Scheme info I have set, I have nothing in the Arguments tab. (This is a new account so I'm not allowed to embed images RIP)

[Scheme Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4N7DP.png)

[Scheme Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZkiK.png)

[Scheme Diagnostics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6prCt.png)

Comment: It sounds like you may accidentally have set your Scheme not to debug this app, or not to hook the debugger to the app automatically at launch.

Comment: @matt I added images of my Scheme settings to the post for you to look at. I'm pretty sure they all should tell the debugger to launch automatically, but I'd be more than delighted to be wrong.

Comment: Yep it's right there in the first screen shot: Executable : Ask On Launch. Fix that to point at the app target.

Comment: Yeah that worked! Strange that the debugger doesn't work with Ask On Launch. Tyvm friend!

Comment: Yepper no worries.

Comment: Do not extend the question to include the answer. Answers go in the answer field. If the problem is solved, delete the question or answer it. Don’t leave it hanging.

Comment: Donezo, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1):

As Matt pointed out, the debugger will not point at the app target if the Executable dropdown (in Scheme Info) is "Ask On Launch". It must have the app itself selected.